# modularization or namespace in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want all the classes to be available under a namespace in a library-based project.

I'm missing a step when it comes to putting all classes under a namespace.

Assume i have two classes in two folders

1. The first step is to export all of them under a library name or namespace
2. The second step is to consume them in a test folder by accessing classes through their library name or namespace

**Expectation/Question:** To be able to access and consume classes through a common library name, for instance `new mylib.Foo()` or `new mylib.Bar()`

## Definition

### src/a/Foo.ts

```
export module mylib {
    export class Foo {
    }
}
```

### src/b/Bar.ts

```
export module mylib {
    export class Bar {
    }
}
```

### src/index.ts

```
import { Foo } from './a/Foo'
import { Bar } from './b/Bar'

export { Foo, Bar }
```

---

## Testing

### test/a/Foo.spec.ts

```
import { mylib } from "../src";

test("constructor"), () = {
   const foo = new mylib.Foo() // expectation
}
```

### test/b/Bar.spec.ts

```
test("constructor"), () = {
   const bar = new mylib.Bar() // expectation
}
```

Comment: It's hard to answer a post that does not include a question. Please edit and clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: please see Expectation/Question

Comment: Is it important to you to use the TypeScript `module` syntax, specifically, as opposed to modern standard JavaScript module syntax? (You're mixing the two above currently.)

Comment: I'm not fixated on any syntax; modern and standard are better. Just being able to package and consume classes (separate files) through a namespace would be sufficient. As long as library is usable for web/react and react-native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want the end result you've asked about and aren't specifically trying to use TypeScript's `module` syntax, you can simplify a bit and then have a couple of options.

The simplification is that you don't need those `export module mylib { /* ... */ }` wrappers in `Foo.ts` and `Bar.ts`, just:

```
export class Foo
    // ...
}
```

and

```
export class Bar
    // ...
}
```

Then it becomes a question of how you want those imported from `index.ts`.

#### Module namespace object

What you have now in `index.ts` is actually just fine for one way it could be used: It creates two named exports, `Foo` and `Bar`. If you want to write code using those via a `mylib` object, you can create that on import:

```
import * as mylib from "../src";
//     ^^^^^^^^^^
```

That `import` syntax says "Import the *module namespace object* for the module and assign it to a binding called `mylib`." If the module namespace object doesn't already exist for that module, it'll be created.

Usage once it's imported is as shown in the question, `mylib.Foo` etc.

But doing it that way, it's also possible to use `import { Foo } from "../src";` and/or `import { Bar } from "../src";`. Normally that's a good thing, but if you don't want to allow that, you won't want to do individual named exports.

Note that `import * as mylib` will defeat tree-shaking, if that's important to what you're doing. (Which is part of why `import { Foo }` and such are normally a good thing.) But it's the person *using* your library who makes that decision; your library doesn't prevent tree-shaking by itself.

#### Export an object

If you don't want to do the module namespace object approach above, you could export an object from `index.ts`:

```
export const mylib = { Foo, Bar };
```

...or perhaps export it frozen so properties can't be added, removed, or reassigned:

```
export const mylib = Object.freeze({ Foo, Bar });
```

Then import is as you've shown it in the question:

```
import { mylib } from "../src";
```

And usage is `mylib.Foo` etc.

Beware that this defeats tree-shaking, and not just based on how users use it, but at the library level (by not having `Foo` and `Bar` exports people could use instead). I wouldn't recommend it.

#### Both

Finally, you could support both named individual exports and a single named object export. In that case, the exports in `index.ts` would look like this:

```
export { Foo, Bar };
export const mylib = Object.freeze({Foo, Bar});
```

If you do that, you leave it up to people using the code whether to use `import { Foo }` or `import { mylib }`. That keeps the library friendly to tree-shaking, while also providing a named export for the library as a whole if that's useful.

Comment: Thanks; this is working. Question: Is this a universal solution for all environments? (TypeScript, Web JS, React and React Native)? I'm relatively new to TypeScript.

Comment: @Source - Yes. JavaScript's native module format (sometimes called "ESM" for ECMAScript Modules) is directly supported by all modern browsers, recent Node.js versions, Deno, and Bun. But on top of that, TypeScript can output a different module format if necessary, so if you needed to support obsolete environments that didn't have ESM, you could do that too. See the documentation on the [`module` option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/theory.html#the-module-output-format) for details.

Comment: does it work with interfaces? I also defined interfaces, for example 'export interface IFoo{}`, I have imported IFoo from the file but `export const mylib = {IFoo, Foo};` doesn't like it, IFoo is highlighted red in my IDE.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77595354/modularization-and-exporting-interfaces

Comment: @Source - No, the rollup part of this (the `mylib` part) doesn't work for interfaces. Frankly, I'd suggest just using discrete exports (the `Foo` and `Bar` stuff). Gathering everything together into a `mylib` object (conceptually or actually) is a bit old-fashioned, a relic of the old CommonJS module days.

Comment: I see, is it possible that some kind of definition of `IFoo` gets exported to minified file, or the interface is just there to enforce compile-time function signature of classes

Comment: @Source - Interfaces don't exist at runtime. Almost **all** of TypeScript doesn't exist at runtime (the only exception is that `enum`s have a small runtime aspect). It's all about adding a layer of type-checking on top of JavaScript, which is then removed during compilation.

Comment: I'm thinking, how if I distribute all my interfaces along with the minified lib, just like it's done in C/C++, and users of the library can use both in their code.

Comment: @Source - When compiling (not *minifying*, though you can do that too), you can have TypeScript output a `.d.ts` file that provides type information for your library. See [Declaration Files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) and [`declaration` and related options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#declaration).

Comment: I see, I added, `"declaration": true,  "declarationDir": "./types"` and the directory was populated with all `.d.ts` files. You mean users of the library can use interface types from the types folder in their source project. Is that how its done in the TypeScript ecosystem? So I'll publish this types folder to npm along with the compiled version?

Comment: @Source - Right. You include a `types` key in `exports` in your `package.json` when publishing that points to the types (as I understand it -- beware I've never published a library on `npm`). You might look at how [Preact](https://github.com/preactjs/preact) does it, since unlike React, Preact provides their own types for their lib. (React doesn't; its types are "aftermarket" if you will, from [Definitely Typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react) rather than from the React team).

Comment: This exports is deep and its scope is big, i have to study more.