# modularization and exporting interfaces

Tags: typescript

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77594573/modularization-or-namespace-in-typescript) worked perfectly fine for concrete classes, until I came across importing interfaces, how do you work with interface types and exporting them from your library along with concrete classes.

### src/include/IFoo.ts

```
export interface IFoo {}
```

### src/index.ts

```
import {IFoo} from "./include/IFoo";
import {Foo} from "./Foo.ts";

export const mylib = {IFoo, Foo}; // error: TS2693:  IFoo  only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

**Error**: I understand that interface is not a value type in TypeScript but then how the users of the library expect to work with an interface provided by the library instead of the actual concrete class.

**Question/Expectation**: I'd like to use the implementation of a class through it's interface.

### test/Foo.spec.ts

```
const foo: mylib.IFoo = new mylib.Foo(); // Expectation IFoo var
```

Comment: export type { Foo } from "./Foo.ts"

That should work or do you require namespaces?
The problem here is that you use IFoo as a property of an object.

Comment: yes it has to be part of the namespace, `mylib.IFoo`.

Comment: I added an example for namespacing

Answer (score 0):

The error is not regarding exporting.

```js
export const mylib = {IFoo, Foo}; // error: TS2693:  IFoo  only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

`{ IFoo, Foo }` Creates a new Object and IFoo would be a property where the value would be IFoo type. Types do not service the TS compilation and can not be used in values.

```js
export type { Foo } from "./Foo.ts"
```

Should do the trick, if you need namespaces have a look here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html

Lets create a little example:

*test.lib.ts*

```
export interface Shape {
  x: string;
  y: string;
}
```

*lib.ts*

```
import { Shape as S } from "./test.lib";

export namespace myLib {
  export interface Shape extends S {}

  export function Test() {
    return "Hello";
  }
}
```

How to use:

```
import { myLib } from "./lib";
const shape: myLib.Shape = { x: "", y: "" };
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `export type Shape `, is this applicable to `interface` types?

Comment: Ah sorry forgot about that. I updated it to use interfaces. There might be a smarter way but this works.

Make sure you really need interfaces. Read about augmentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

Comment: I like this, but I'm a little thrown off, can you please amend the code to include class `Foo` and interface `IFoo` from my example. Also, both Foo and IFoo are defined in their own respective files.